# Ios Custom Keyboard - spotlight search

Tags: objective-c

i am working on a custom keyboard with my own autocorrect logic in objective-C. I want to turn off autocorrect when the keyboard pops in spotlight or other search fields. How to check if the keyboard pops up in search fields like spotlight?

Comment: I am able to disable autocorrect when uikeyboardtypeurlandwebsearch. But I want to turn off autocorrect in spotlight and other search fields e.g. Searching videos in YouTube app.

Comment: I have been googling a lot but could not find answer to this